# CoreData: why not refresh UI when book.isPublic toggled

Tags: core-data, swiftui

'@Environment(.managedObjectContext) var context' will monitor the changes of context. When I click the button to toggle isPublic, I think it will cause to UI refreshing, Button text will change, But not, WHY?

```
struct BookInfoView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    var isPublic: Bool { return book.isPublic }
    
    let book: Book
    
    var body: some View {
        print("refresh"); return
            Group {
                Button(action: onPublicToggled) {
                    Text(isPublic ? "private" : "public")
                }
            }
    }
    
    func onPublicToggled() {
        context.perform {
            book.isPublic.toggle()
            try? context.save()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to observe a `Book` changes via `ObservedObject` wrapper, like

```
struct BookInfoView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @ObservedObject var book: Book
    
    var body: some View {
        print("refresh"); return
            Group {
                Button(action: onPublicToggled) {
                    Text(book.isPublic ? "private" : "public")
                }
            }
    }
    
    func onPublicToggled() {
        context.perform {
            book.isPublic.toggle()
            try? context.save()
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context` relates to `context` itself, not to your CoreData objects.*

Comment: I don't understand it. I use 'let book: Book', because it from booklist of previous View。`BookInfoView(book: book)`. if book is @ObservedObject, how to implement BookInfoView.init?

Comment: You don't need explicit `init` in this case, it the same `BookInfoView(book: book)`, cause it is a struct.

Comment: and `@interface NSManagedObject : NSObject` is not a ObservableObject, why we can @ObservedObject it?

Comment: NSManagedObject does conform to ObservableObject

Comment: So, '@Environment(.managedObjectContext) var context' cannot monitor the changes of context. is it right? I can remove it, using CoreStack.shared.context instead.

Comment: Yes, I found it. NSManagedObject does conform to ObservableObject